# Failed to copy Field with expresion which contains call to function in Tablix SSRS

Tags: function, reporting-services, copy, expression

In a SSRS report (VS 2019), in a Tablix I have a cell which contains an expression like below:

```
=Code.Quotient(Fields!MyField1.Value, Fields!MyField2.Value, -1)
```

where Quotient is a function I wrote in code.

When I do a copy of the Tablix (in the same report), for the copied Tablix, in the same cell, I have

```
=Code.Quotient
```

Is any way to copy correctly the Tablix?

The function is:

```
Function Quotient(ByVal numerator As Decimal, denominator As Decimal, custom as Decimal) As Decimal
    If denominator = 0 Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Return ((numerator / denominator) + custom)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: is the dataset name property of the tablix being preserved? If not then set this before examining the textbox. Just a guess though...

Comment: The Dataset is the same for both Tablix. I want to add that if I open the expression
=Code.Quotient(Fields!MyField1.Value, Fields!MyField2.Value, -1)
The word Quotient is underline with red
Also at the bottom of edit window expression, it signals that is a bug. When I want to see the bug, there is nothing in error window.
I have to stress that the expression is working as expected

Comment: Intellisense does not work in a lot of cases in SSRS so this does not surprise me but I would ignore it. Intellisense also does not work for other things like the return value of a lookup expression. So if it is working, just ignore the red highlights.